# jquerymodal disappear after 1 second of load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using https://jquerymodal.com/
But on page load it appears for 1 second then it disappears.

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.css" />
    <script>
        jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
            setTimeout(function(){window.jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
                /* Session Storage with Bootstrop Modal box */
                    (function () {
                        if (sessionStorage.getItem("modalShown") !== 'true') {
                            jQuery('#login-modal').modal({ fadeDuration: 250,  fadeDelay: 0.80 });
                            sessionStorage.setItem("modalShown", "true");
                        }
                    })();
                /* End Session Storage with Bootstrop Modal box */
            }); },500);

        });
    </script>
```

```
<div id="login-modal" class="modal">
      <p>Content here</p>
</div>
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are binding your function with two events

Try this

```js
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.css" />
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            setTimeout(function(){
                if (sessionStorage.getItem("modalShown") !== 'true') {
                    jQuery('#login-modal').modal({ fadeDuration: 250,  fadeDelay: 0.80 });
                    sessionStorage.setItem("modalShown", "true");
                }
            },500);
        });
    </script>
```